# Twitter app related Auto refresh Features

Tags: android, twitter

I want autorefresh feature in my app, where my tweets are automatically refreshed and if newer tweets are there they will come automatically without user intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to update your timeline periodically.

Comment: how I have to use it,my timeline is coming but after clicking I want auto refresh features

Comment: @payal Have you read through the instructions on the page I linked?

Comment: ya i have but not getting enough so need..somthing

Comment: Actually I am using a method..that is Loader New tweets!!

Comment: private void loadNewerTweets() {
    headerView.showProgress();
    new LoadMoreAsyncTask(this, twitter, adapter.getFirstId(), true).execute();
  }

Comment: but when i click on it then it will happen and get new tweets but I want Automatically..

Comment: ...so you need to call that method periodically using a Service.

Comment: yaa i have tried but not getting proper solutions please tell me how it has to use..means bind with service how??

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/